# Segmentation Fault upon pointer dereferencing order

Tags: c, pointers, struct, segmentation-fault, dereference

I'm trying to read a Matrix as here:
I've tried it on Cygwin, and MinGW compilers.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct _Matrix {
    int **data;
    int m;
    int n;
} Matrix;

Matrix *read_matrix(void) {
    Matrix *A;
    int i, j;
    int **ptr;

    A = (Matrix *) malloc(sizeof(Matrix));
    if(A == NULL) {
        return NULL;
    }

    printf("Enter m : ");
    scanf("%d", &A->m);
    printf("Enter n : ");
    scanf("%d", &A->n);

    ptr = (int **) malloc(A->m * A->n * sizeof(int));
    /*-- >> A->data = ptr; << --*/
    if(A->data == NULL) {
        return NULL;
    }
    printf("\n");
    for(i=0; i<A->m; ++i) {
        for(j=0; j<A->n; ++j) {
            printf("Enter element [%d][%d] : ", i, j);
            scanf("%d", &ptr[i][j]);
        }
    }
    A->data = ptr;
    return A;
}

int main() {
    Matrix *A;

    A = read_matrix();
    free(A->data); /* A-- A->data is NULL --*/
    free(A);
    return 0;
}
```

If I set `A->data` before reading in values, I get a `SEGMENTATION FAULT`.
However, the code here does not appear to crash. However `A->data` returns `NULL`. What am I missing here?

Comment: `ptr = (int **) malloc(A->m * A->n * sizeof(int));` ? Why would you allocate something `sizeof(type)` and expect to use it as a `type**`? One way to avoid this is to `ptr = malloc(A->m * A->n * sizeof(*ptr));`, which does the right thing automatically.

Comment: Try `ptr = (int**) malloc(A->m * A->n * sizeof(int**));`

Comment: @hagrawal: No. Just no.

Comment: @user2338150 Can you point out where and when exactly you have error.

Comment: There is no matrix (aka 2D array) in your code. A pointer is not an array!

Comment: @hagrawal: Do not cast `void *` to other pointers! C is not C++.

Comment: `ptr[i][j]` : `ptr[i]` is not initialized (point to not allocated memory).

Comment: All the problems I understand are due to misinterpreting `int*` as `int` in 'sizeof' . Since I need elements, instead of pointers, I must use single indirection pointer as `user3121023` said. But, the two anomalities of order of statement, and `A->data` being `NULL`  still need pondering.

Comment: You scribbled over memory in your `ptr[i][j]` loop so anything could happen really

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A single pointer is all that is needed for the allocation being used.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct _Matrix {
    int *data;           //single pointer
    int m;
    int n;
} Matrix;

Matrix *read_matrix(void) {
    Matrix *A;
    int i, j;

    A = malloc(sizeof(Matrix));
    if(A == NULL) {
        return NULL;
    }

    printf("Enter m : ");
    scanf("%d", &A->m);
    printf("Enter n : ");
    scanf("%d", &A->n);

    A->data = malloc(A->m * A->n * sizeof(int));
    if(A->data == NULL) {
        return A;
    }
    printf("\n");
    for(i=0; i<A->m; ++i) {
        for(j=0; j<A->n; ++j) {
            printf("Enter element [%d][%d] : ", i, j);
            scanf("%d", &A->data[( j * A->m) + i]);
        }
    }
    return A;
}

int main() {
    Matrix *A;
    int i;
    int j;

    A = read_matrix();
    if ( A) {
        if ( A->data) {
            for(i=0; i<A->m; ++i) {
                for(j=0; j<A->n; ++j) {
                    printf("A[%d][%d]= %d\n", i, j, A->data[( j * A->m) + i]);
                }
            }
            free(A->data);
        }
        free(A);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: There seems to be some problem with this code, at input `m=3, n=1`. It crashes like : `Heap block at 005E1508 modified at 005E151C past requested size of c`. From my understanding, operator precedence might not be the cause of this problem. What could it be?

Comment: Thank you for pointing it out. I made the same mistake. The index order here is `Column-Major`. I had mistakenly taken it as `Row-Major`. For `Row-Major', `A->data[ i * A->n + j]` should have been used.